# WritableBitmapImage from BitmapImage with no source Windows Phone 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have an `BitmapImage` which is generated by application itself and have no sourceFile or `URI`. Now i have to convert this image to `WritableBitmapImage` in order to save it, according to [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/save-and-retrieve-image-file-from-stream-to-local-storage-in-windows-phone-81-runtime-apps). But all the methods require sourceFile or URI.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to extract the pixels from a BitmapImage after the fact.

As you note, if you have the source image then you can create a WriteableBitmap from that.

Since WritableBitmap and BitmapImage are both ImageSources they can be used the same way in most cases, so if you know you'll need access to the pixels when you create the BitmapImage then you can usually create a WriteableBitmap instead.

Once the BitmapImage is created and the original source is no longer available the closest you can get is to use [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) to render the displayed Image control into a new bitmap from which you can extract the pixels with [GetPixelData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.getpixelsasync.aspx).

This will be a second generation image though and for large images will likely have lost data to resizing interpolation between the original and the rendering.

I'd recommend using a WriteableBitmap instead of a BitmapImage to begin with when generating the original image.